# Octave Store Iteration Values of Each Loop

Tags: for-loop, matrix, iteration, octave, metrics

I need your help in a project of mine. I am using the for loop in octave to calculate the mean, standard deviation, and variance of some data and store this information in a matrix called metrics. The data consist of 19 columns and 15000 rows and are stored in the epochs variable. My code is this:

```
# Preallocate memory for the epoch data
epochs = zeros(15000, 19);
# Preallocate memory for metrics
metrics = zeros(3, 19);

for i = 1:20
  start_idx = (i - 1) * epoch_length + 1;
  end_idx = start_idx + epoch_length -1;
  epochs(:,i) = patient1(start_idx:end_idx);
  
  # Calculate the mean, standard deviation, and variance for multiple EEG channels
  meanValue = mean(epochs,1); # mean of all EEG channels
  stdValue = std(epochs,0,1); # standard deviation of all EEG channels
  varValue = var(epochs,0,1); # variance of all EEG channels


  # Collect metrics in a single matrix
  metrics(1,:) = meanValue;
  metrics(2,:) = stdValue;
  metrics(3,:) = varValue;
```

The problem i'm having is that this code only stores the data of the last for iteration both in the epochs as well as in the metrics matrices, whereas i would like the code to produce 20 diferrent epoch and metrics matrices each one containing values of every one of the 20 iterations.

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You preallocate for 19 iterations, that should be 20. When assigning into `metrics`, you need to use the loop index: `metrics(1,i) = …`. `mean(epochs,1)` computes the mean over all the columns of the array, not only the one you assigned stuff to in this loop iteration.

Comment: You can do this without a loop. `epochs = patient1(1:epoch_length*20); epochs = reshape(epochs,epoch_length,20); metrics = [mean(epochs,1); std(epochs,0,1); var(epochs,0,1)];`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks a lot for your response but to be honest i am really confused. To make my issue simpler. Lets say i only want the code to provide me with 20 iterations of the epochs matrix:

`# Preallocate memory for the epoch data
epochs = zeros(15000, 19);

for i = 1:20
  start_idx = (i - 1) * epoch_length + 1;
  end_idx = start_idx + epoch_length -1;
  epochs(:,i) = patient1(start_idx:end_idx);
  `

What do I have to change so i get 20 epochs matrices each one for every iteration?

Comment: In that code you get 20 columns in one matrix, not 20 matrices. You don’t want 20 matrices. But as I said before, the allocation is wrong, should be `zeros(15000, 20)` (20, not 19). You probably also want `end_idx = start_idx + epoch_length;` (no -1), and you need `epoch_length` for be 15000. Better change the allocation to be `zeros(epoch_length, 20)`, then you’re sure the size is right.